How do I fix monospace fonts once and for all?
Every time I open a programming site on my Samsung Zflip 4 (both Chrome and Firefox browsers), I am seeing something like this:

while iOs users are enjoying the luxury of this:

Another example, and basically any other site with monospaced fonts.
Is there a way to fix other than istalling a bunch of random "font manager" apps, none of which does the thing?

Unclear which browser you are using and if you've tried/rejected alternate browsers.

I tried Chrome and Firefox, identical results

Related or similar StackOverflow post: HTML  tag contents resizing on android which appears to be a  site issue as the web dev using the PC Chrome/Firefox developer tools set to mobile view will see a 'good' view which doesn't reflect reality on a mobile device. The positive is that the site has a github repo: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues but as this is 'tutorial' content may be of lower priority should anyone create an issue ticket.

Looks similar, but I am sorry, how is this a site issue? The browser is given a clear hint "use monospaced font here please" and if the solution is to somehow install "correct" fonts then I do not understand why Samsung or Xiaomi QA teams disregard issues with the fonts they ship with their devices. Reminder: iOs mobile devices do not have this problem, nor do desktop browsers.

@Morrison Chang
I have put together a minimal example of why this is not a site problem (because basically any site with monospaced fonts will look like this on Android phones) like for example github  https://gist.github.com/megasuperlexa/8b971ce00b8981cd0c9c22c0ede81859

I stand corrected on "site issue" but sadly a 'multi-browser fix' will require effort on the website author as Android has had this problem for a while, see: How do I fix monospace spaces not being correct width in Android Chrome/Firefox?

My objective is (obviously) not to fix all the sites I visit on the Internet, but rather solely my device, wich as I understand simply does not carry "correct" monospace fonts out of the factory. Will appreciate any reliable guidance for this.

Do add if rooting is allowed as a possible option. I've discovered that Android has made it impossible to add custom system fonts so without root, Samsung adding/overriding default fonts, or a custom browser (not following font fallback convention and / or has override flag/plugin), I have doubts on finding a satisfying answer.

So by 2017 the humanity learned that fonts are better parsed in user mode and not kernel.. why 7 years later we still have devices (and not a cheap ones) that still make people suffer because of "possible kernel mode execution"? ok, enough lament ) But I now seriously consider putting up an online petition to Google or maybe device manufacturers to somehow consider fixing this at last on their end.

Adding more context (but not a fix), Android uses Roboto and Noto fonts, however as others found that unicode box-drawing does not render correctly in browsers due to font fallback rules, there is an open issue in the Roboto repo: Several metrics issues in Roboto Mono worth fixing together but I fear this note holds & site fonts is working solution

so the only plausible solutions are to root my phone and swap monospace font or wait till somebody fixes Roboto font and makes it available to android vendors. @Morrison Chang if you make this an answer I can award you this question bounty even though this is not the solution I desired.

btw, today I learned the problem exists not only in browsers, but also in other apps like messengers e.g. Telegram and Slack. So, 100% Android issue and not even web related.

TLDR:

There is a known bug in the Android system fonts.
Apple makes sure that the same fonts/font files are used across devices/OS versions.
Web browsers usually use system fonts for rendering so a custom browser with a font fallback configuration may work.
Other Android apps that use the Android system fonts may encounter the issue.
Only Google or the device manufacturer can add/modify the font files unless the device is rooted.

Android locks down system fonts, issues with fonts that aren't handled by the website or a particular browser will require root to modify system font files or a different browser that can handle font selection differently. Apple ensures the same fonts across their ecosystem so web developers on a Mac will see the same fonts on iOS devices.
Detailed Answer
So as discovered unicode box-drawing does not render correctly in browsers so websites using box-drawing or ASCII art unicode characters need to be aware of how monospace characters/fixed-width fonts are rendering on a variety of devices/OS variants.
Browsers generally use the system fonts to do the rendering.
On Android there are a limited set of predefined font families provided known as Roboto and Noto
Apple has defined a large set of fonts to exist across their platforms (iOS/MacOS/AppleTV) so that those using browser based developer tools won't see any differences across the Apple platforms:
Taken from: https://developer.apple.com/fonts/system-fonts/ on 2024-05-03

American Typewriter
16.0d2e4
iOS  macOS  tvOS
American Typewriter Bold
16.0d2e4
iOS  macOS  tvOS
American Typewriter Condensed
16.0d2e4
iOS  macOS  tvOS
American Typewriter Condensed Bold
16.0d2e4
iOS  macOS  tvOS
American Typewriter Condensed Light
16.0d2e4
iOS  macOS  tvOS
American Typewriter Light
16.0d2e4
iOS  macOS  tvOS
American Typewriter Semibold
16.0d2e4 iOS macOS tvOS

What this means though is that users of Linux or Windows may see different font files used for fixed-width fonts unless the website developer is aware of such things. An unaware web developer using PC browser tools checking for mobile layout will still the fonts that are on the PC, thus when checking on a real device with different font files will see undesirable results.
Does Google/Android know a problem exists with box-drawing and ASCII art?
Based on issue ticket: Several metrics issues in Roboto Mono worth fixing together  the font team is aware of problem however based on this comment there may be no easy fix from the font team.
So wait does this affect all Android apps?
Yes. Unless the Android app author includes their own fonts for box-drawing / ASCII art the app will use the system default fonts with the problem. Attempting to 'hack' the app and add fonts involves changing the code of the app to use the new specific font files rather than the default system fonts.
Okay so can I add the correct fonts to my Android device
Fonts are basically a tiny programs that draws what you see. Android locks down system fonts as they consider it an attack vector so unless you root your device to change fonts OR Google/Samsung/the device manufacturer adds/overrides the existing system fonts those errant font files will exist. As browsers use the system fonts as convention for fallback, a browser not following font fallback convention or has a setting/plugin for override would be an option.
And if I can't/won't root my device unless the website author or Android app author adds support for a font that handles box-drawing/ASCII art on Android devices, its going to look bad?
Correct, sadly that is the case.
Resources/References
Really Good, Bad UTF-8 example test data (closed)
Default font set on Android
How to prevent different browsers rendering fonts differently?
Android Monospace doesn't behave as a fixed-pitch
How do I fix monospace spaces not being correct width in Android Chrome/Firefox?
Why has Android made it impossible to install system fonts?

I learned yesterday that this issue also present in Slack and Telegram apps for Android (source code display feature, uses monospaced font), so browsers and webtools are actually irrelevant here. Otherwise great answer.

I tried that with 5 browsers on my Samsung Note 20 and on Windows 10. Which means it is not a browser issue.  Its an issue with the site.  It has specified a font that does not exist naturally on Android.  If it worries you, you need to install that font on your mobile.
Alternatively, request the author of the page to fix it.  It is normal to specify alternate fonts that can be used on your web pages.

I think this is not true, I am seeing a font family specified on that element which means client browser is free to choose whatever is in the system as long as it is monospace: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace

Rohit could you kindly give more details of how you are installing fonts on your mobile?
